# Построчный ввод на Python

Tags: python, input

Мне нужно составить список из строк, построчно вводимых с клавиатуры. Например, дано:

```
20
30
005
```

Я должен получить список из строк: `["20", "30", "005"]`. Заранее не известно, сколько строк будет введено. Я не понимаю, как отследить конец ввода. Если я буду писать так:

```
  a = []
  while input():
      a.append(input())
```

то получается, что первый инпут я не записываю в список, а второй записываю, и если второго инпута нет, то будет ошибка, так как нечего записывать в список. Подскажите, как сделать. Я только начал изучать Питон (Пайтон). Благодарю заранее за любой совет.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте такой способ:

```
a = []
while True:
    try:
        a.append(input())
    except EOFError:
        break
print(a)
```

Когда вывод закончится и `input()` не сможет считать очередную строку, то породится исключение `EOFError`, которое можно поймать и обработать. В этот момент поток ввода завершится.

Answer (score 2):

```
a=[]
i=True
while i:
   i=input()
   if i: a.append(i)
```

Если оставить строку пустой, ввод прекратится.

Answer (score 1):

Можно таким способом:

```
In [9]: while True:
   ...:     inp = input()
   ...:     if not inp: break
   ...:     array.append(inp)
```

Цикл остановится если ввод будет пуст.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете применить функцию `input()` из стандартного модуля [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fileinput.html), которая читает «до бесконечности» *ввод из стандартного потока* - пока не встретится признак конца файла (EOF - End of File):

```
import fileinput

a = []
for s in fileinput.input():
    a.append(s.strip())
```

Ввод окончится *симуляцией признака конца файла* - нажатием на <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (вместо ввода дальнейшего числа) - см. тоже [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/928394/233990) на вопрос [Признак конца ввода Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/928248/233990).

Метод `strip()` применяется для удаления символа `\n` в конце введенных строк.