# Признак конца ввода Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

> На стандартном потоке ввода задаётся последовательность целых чисел.
>       Каждое число последовательности не меньше `-20000000` и не больше `20000000`.
>       Всего последовательность состоит не более чем из `40` чисел.
>       Последовательность завершается признаком конца ввода.
>       На стандартный поток вывода напечатайте сумму этих чисел.

Не могу понять что такое признак конца ввода, пытался сделать через `input()`
кидает `WrongAnswer`. Предполагаю, что нужно делать через `sys.stdin()`, но как, не могу понять, каким образом нужно остановить чтение из потока, что такое признак конца ввода, и как это все сделать на Питоне?

По С++ нашел кучу ответов, но не могу применить это на Питоне.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Случай *«конец файла»* возникает, когда уже *нету что читать из источника дат*, обычно из файла.

Но ввод из *терминала* практически *никогда не окончатся*, и потому в каждой операционной системе *выделена комбинация клавишей* (обычно <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), которая драйвером терминала *интерпретируется как конец файла.*

Значит, ввод для вашей программы может выглядеть так:

```
777 25 -86400
-1456 666
```

после чего пользователь нажмёт (на новой строке) на <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Читать стандартный поток ввода удобно с применением метода `input()` стандартного модуля [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fileinput.html), который распознает <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> как конец ввода:

```
import fileinput

total = 0

for line in fileinput.input():     # читает строку после строки, пока нет Ctrl+D
    lst = line.split()             # lst будет списком отдельных чисел, но как строк
    numbers = map(int, lst)        # применит функцию int к всякому элементу списка lst
    total += sum(numbers)          # добавит сумму чисел из списка numbers к total

print("Сумма:", total)
```

---

Тест:

> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5
> 6 
> 7 8 9 10
> Сумма: 55
> ```

(После ввода последнего числа - `10` - пользователь нажал на <kbd>Enter</kbd> и затем - на новой строке - на <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.)

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло )

Comment: @sorvihead, не стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Признаком конца файла является [EOF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EOF). Например, функции чтения языка Си вернут константу `EOF`, если данные в файле закончились.

В Питоне прочитать все данные со стандартного потока ввода можно так:

```
from sys import stdin
text = stdin.read()
```

Также можно обрабатывать данные по строкам:

```
from sys import stdin
for line in sys.stdin:
    #
```

В вашем случае можно получить список введённых чисел так:

```
from sys import stdin
text = stdin.read()
l = list(map(int, text.split()))
```